# How to compare two cases Id's to each other and display the child case if the the parent and the child case Id match

Tags: lighting-web-component

I have a lwc that grabs cases. The cases have child cases, I would like to display the child case with the parent case. I am still new to LWC's. I can get the parent case and display that data fine. But when i want to compare the the two Ids and then set a value to true to show that section if both are equal. doesn't just load the one child case. It loads them all. So i was wondering what is the best way to go about this? I have read and people are saying to use getters. I tried to do a child lwc to show the child case's. But with that it only grabs the last Id since the Id is taken out of the for loop.

```
import getProjectTrackerExtension from '@salesforce/apex/ParentClass.getProjectTrackerExtension';
import newSitePower from '@salesforce/apex/ParentClass.newSitePower';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

export default class JobWrapper extends LightningElement {
 
 @api selectedAccountId;
 @api tableData;
 @api childJobSelected;
 @track searchProject = 'AP-Add';
 @track parentPowerId;
 @track childSearch;
 @track newSite = false;


 get options() {
   return [
           { label: 'AP-Add', value: 'AP-Add'},
           { label: 'Backbone-Add  ', value: 'Backbone-Add'},
           { label: 'AP-Add-Dedicated', value: 'AP-Add-Dedicated'},
           { label: 'AP-Replace', value: 'AP-Replace' },
           { label: 'Backbone-Replace', value: 'Backbone-Replace' },
           { label: 'New Site', value: 'New Site' },
       ];
}

 @wire(getProjectTrackerExtension,{projectList: '$searchProject'})
 
 projectHander(response){
     this.projectResponse = response;
     let data = response.data;
     let error = response.error;
     
     if(data){
       this.tableData = data;
       this.newArray = tempAllRecords;
       if(this.searchProject === "New Site"){
         this.childSearch = "New Site";
       }
     }
     if(error){
       console.log(error);
     }
   }
 

 // Tracking the power It also loops once. not multiples so its passing all the Ids in at once not one at a time.

 @wire(newSitePower, {param1: '$tableData', param2: '$childSearch'})
 projectPowerHandler(response){
   let pData = response.data;
   let pError = response.error;
   if(pData){
     this.newSitePowerTable = pData;
     console.log(this.newSitePowerTable);
     console.log(this.parentPowerId);
     console.log(this.tableData);
     console.log(this.childSearch);
     if(this.childSearch === "New Site"){
       for (let p = 0; p < this.tableData.length; p++) {
         let parentId = this.tableData[p].Case__c;
         for (let c = 0; c < this.newSitePowerTable.length; c++) {
           let childObject = this.newSitePowerTable[c].Case__r;
           // console.log(parentId);
           // console.log(childObject.ParentId);
            
           if(parentId === childObject.ParentId){
             console.log('true');  
             this.newSite = true;
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
   if(pError){
     console.log('Error')
   }
 }
}
```

```
<template for:each={newSitePowerTable} for:item="powerData">
    <template iterator:it={powerData.Case__r.ParentId}>
       <template if:true={newSite}>
           <tr key={powerData.Id}>
              <td>{powerData.Case__r.ParentId}</td>
            </tr>
          </template>
        </template>
       </template>
```

```
public with sharing class ParentClass {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Project_Tracker__c> getProjectTrackerExtension(string projectList){

       return [SELECT Id,Name,Scope__c,Current_Step__c,Current_Step_Date__c,Next_Step__c,Next_Step_Date__c,Assigned_to_OP_Projected__c,Completion_Difference_Text__c,Description__c,Completion_Difference_Color__c,Case_Number__c,Case__c FROM Project_Tracker__c WHERE Project_Type__c = :projectList];
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Project_Tracker__c> newSitePower(string param){
       return [SELECT Id, Name,Case__r.ParentId FROM Project_Tracker__c WHERE Project_Type__c = 'New Site - Power'];
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a bit of an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I feel like you're trying to ask "how do I display a parent case with its children", or perhaps "how do I display a list of child cases with their parent", or something along those lines, but I'm not sure which. What's your desired output? We can show you how to get there, we just need to know what your original ask is, first.

Comment: Currently we are listing individual projects, this works fine in a for:each. We have now been tasked to link or cluster a larger project that can have a parent case and 2 different child cases (for tracking different aspects of the job). Our original idea was to run a for:each for the parent, print all the data and at the end include a second for:each that passed the Case__c as a param, so we can then compare a 2nd query that has all the possible child cases and find the single record and print its data. We need to pass the ParentId into the if:true condition.

Comment: I also updated the code above to see the parent wire and screen shots of the json data we are pulling.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own issue.

The way i went about is. I created a child component and stuck it in my foreach and stored the parent Case Id in the child variable.

```
<template for:each={newArray}  for:item="projectData">
  <c-job-Power child-job-power={projectData.Case__c}></c-job-Power>
</template>
```

Then passed that variable into the child and used it in the soql so then it will keep looping over the child.

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire } from 'lwc';
import newSitePower from '@salesforce/apex/childPower.newSitePower';

export default class JobPower extends LightningElement {
    @api childJobPower;
    powerTable;
    
    @wire(newSitePower, {parentPower: '$childJobPower'})
        projectPowerHandler(response){
            let pData = response.data;
            let pError = response.error;
            if(pData){
                console.log(pData);
                this.powerTable = pData;
            }
            if(pError){
                console.log(pError);
            }
        }
    
}
```

```
public with sharing class childPower {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Project_Tracker__c> newSitePower(string parentPower){
       return [SELECT Id, Name,Case__r.ParentId FROM Project_Tracker__c WHERE Case__r.ParentId = :parentPower];
    }
}
```

then displayed the data in the child

```
<template>
    <p>hi</p>
    <template for:each={powerTable}  for:item="stuff">
        <span key={stuff.Id}>
            {stuff.Name}
        </span>
    </template>
</template>
```